# How to install gluezilla-dev?

Tags: installation, mono, libraries

`gluezilla` was removed from latest Ubuntu repository for some silly reason. This library is necessary for mono web libraries to work properly (without `gluezilla` the web browser component doesn't work).

How do I install it on Ubuntu? It has an incredible dependency tree of packages that were in older Ubuntu versions but for some reason aren't in current Ubuntu. Is there any way to install it other than downgrading to older Ubuntu?

Answer (score -1):

Updated for 12.04

To install, download the [32bit](http://pkgs.org/debian-squeeze/debian-main-i386/libgluezilla_2.6-2_i386.deb.html) or the [64bit](http://pkgs.org/debian-squeeze/debian-main-amd64/libgluezilla_2.6-2_amd64.deb.html), and then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the folder where the download is saved, more that likely its Downloads, and then run the command below.

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name.deb>
```

To download xulrunner click [Here](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/), and for libhunspell-1.2-0 click [Here](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libhunspell-1.2-0)

Comment: this doesn't work because it requires lot of packages that aren't available in this version of ubuntu

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04, I tried installing libgluezilla_2.6-2_amd64.deb, but it requires xulrunner-1.9.1; so downloaded xulrunner-1.9.1_1.9.1.16-20_amd64.deb, but it requires libhunspell-1.2-0, and in Ubuntu 12.04 repository there is the 1.3 version... so I stopped